# uncertainty of slope.

Tags: statistics

i have a graph that i fitted a line on it using least squares fit.
Now i want to calculate the uncertainty of slope.
i calculated the standard error of slope and now i have this question:

the uncertainty of slope is "slope ± standard error" or it is the confidence interval???!

please help me. i really need the answer. i searched in many books but unfortunately i couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Hint: the Wikipedia entry for Simple linear regression answers that.

Comment: Both are some measures of uncertainty.

Comment: Try to show the picture, when you mention about it in your post!

Comment: but which one is better or more accurate?